# http/ssl for nginx and apache virtual host

Tags: apache, nginx

I have apache ssh server, currently it works correctly.

This works

`https://exmaple.com/`

Then now, I want to introduce nginx as reverse-proxy,

what I want to do next is

pass access `https://example.com:8080` to apache.

For now my setting is like this below.

```
server{
        listen 8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        server_name examle.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:443/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

then,

`http://example.com/` it works

`https://example.com` shows `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I am confused.

SSL certification document is installed in apache already.

However I need to set this in nginx as well?

Comment: Need to give to apache with the HTTP like this :  proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1/;
else if you really want to conserver SSL in both you need to declare SSL in both, it's missing in your proxy configuration

Comment: Thankyou ror your help. I installed ssl document in nginx too. then it works. but my final solution is as you mensioned remove https from apache. I use ssl in nginx and redirect with `proxy_pass` to apache 80 port